# Using SAML2.0 artifacts in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, saml-2.0

I want to use SAML2.0 to authenticate users visiting my site with a SSO identity provider. Ideally, I'd like to use SAML 2.0 artifact binding, but, while .Net 4.5 has classes to represent SAML 2.0 statements such as AuthenticationStatement, I can't find any classes for resolving  artifacts. Is this something that's not supported, or am I not looking in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "artifact" is sometimes used for different meanings in SAML2 documentation, so I assume that you mean the [SAML artifact binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616169/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-saml-artifact) (Microsoft uses the term to mean key, token or something else in their [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IdentityModel.Tokens(v=vs.110).aspx)).

So assuming that you mean the artifact binding, there is no support for it in the .NET framework. While there is support for SAML2 *tokens*, their is no support for *bindings* in the core framework.

You'll have to look at third party libraries, or write your own (or help extending an [open source SP](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices)).